# What is the percentage of food that goes to a lamb fetus?

Tags: food, nutrition, pregnancy

Does any one know the percentage of food eaten by a pregnant ewe that goes to the lamb fetus?

Specifically how much does the mother take for her body from every one kilo of food 
and how much does the fetus take?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It is expected that you will do research on your own before asking questions here — for example you could start with this: https://extension.oregonstate.edu/animals-livestock/sheep-goats/nutrition-lambing. –––––––– For details on how to use this site, please check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks! 

Comment: In addition, since the answer to this question will vary considerably by gestational stage please edit your question to clarify what you want — e.g. an average over the entire pregnancy.